# Always getting an error regardless of input

Tags: java

Hi I'm a beginner in java and I can't find the error in my code why it always gets an error and gives me the statement in my first try catch in my override method. Here are the relevant parts of my code.

Here is just the method to replace a line in my text file.

```
static void Replacement() throws IOException{
    try {
        //Instantiating the File class
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\kyle\\Desktop\\MeterReadingAndNumber.txt";
        //Instantiating the Scanner class to read the file
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        //instantiating the StringBuffer class
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        //Reading lines of the file and appending them to StringBuffer
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            buffer.append(sc.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        String fileContents = buffer.toString();

        //closing the Scanner object
        sc.close();
        //Replacing the old line with new line
        fileContents = fileContents.replaceAll(pMRead, presMRead);
        //instantiating the FileWriter class
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
        writer.append(fileContents);
        writer.flush();
    }catch (Exception three){
        return;
    }
}
```

Here I just create the input output window and also write the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Power Utility Billing System");
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    numberLabel = new JLabel("Meter number");
    numberLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
    panel.add(numberLabel);
    numberText = new JTextField(20);
    numberText.setBounds(150, 20, 165, 25);
    panel.add(numberText);
    readingLabel = new JLabel("Meter reading");
    readingLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
    panel.add(readingLabel);
    readingText = new JTextField(20);
    readingText.setBounds(150, 50, 165, 25);
    panel.add(readingText);

    mnum = new JLabel("Meter Number: ");
    mnum.setBounds(10, 110, 200, 25);
    panel.add(mnum);
    ccode = new JLabel("Customer Code: ");
    ccode.setBounds(10, 140, 350, 25);
    panel.add(ccode);
    prevmread = new JLabel("Previous Meter Reading: ");
    prevmread.setBounds(10, 170, 200, 25);
    panel.add(prevmread);
    presmread = new JLabel("Present Meter Reading: ");
    presmread.setBounds(10, 200, 200, 25);
    panel.add(presmread);
    amount = new JLabel("Amount to be paid: ");
    amount.setBounds(10, 230, 200, 25);
    panel.add(amount);
    kwh = new JLabel("Kilowatt Hour used: ");
    kwh.setBounds(10, 260, 200, 25);
    panel.add(kwh);
    updateList = new JLabel("");
    updateList.setBounds(10, 290, 200, 80);
    panel.add(updateList);
    ok = new JButton("OK");
    ok.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    ok.addActionListener(new Main());
    panel.add(ok);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    try {
        mReadAndNum = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "C:\\Users\\kyle\\Desktop\\MeterReadingAndNumber.txt"));
        for (int a = 1; a<11; a++)
        {
            int b = 10000;
            mReadAndNum.write(b+a + "\n");
        }
        for (int x = 50; x<550; x += 50 )
        {
            int y = 1000;
            mReadAndNum.write(y+x + "\n");
        }
        mReadAndNum.flush();
    }catch (Exception one){
        return;
    }
    try {
        customerCode = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\kyle\\Desktop\\CustomerCode.txt"));
        for (int d = 1; d<11; d++)
        {
            int e = 10000;
            customerCode.write(e+d + "\n");
        }
        for (int c = 1; c<11; c++)
        {
            customerCode.write(c + "\n");
        }
        customerCode.flush();
    }catch (Exception two)
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

Here is the part that gets the error.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
    try {
        int numText = Integer.parseInt(numberText.getText());
        int readText = Integer.parseInt(readingText.getText());
        presMRead = Integer.toString(readText);
        int index = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("C:\\Users\\kyle\\Desktop\\MeterReadingAndNumber.txt"));
            String s;
            for (int g = 1; g<11; g++){
                s = br.readLine();
                if (s.equals(String.valueOf(numText))){
                    bool = true;
                    index = index + g;
                    break;

                }
                else{
                    bool = false;
                }
            }
            String s1;
            for (int h = 0; h<index+10; h++){
                s1 = br.readLine();
                if (h==index+10){
                    pMRead = s1;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception one){
            return;
        }
        int pMRead1 = Integer.parseInt(pMRead);
        String customer1 = "";
        double payment = 0;
        double kwhUsed = 0;

            if (readText < pMRead1){
                readText = readText + 10000;
            }
            kwhUsed = readText - pMRead1;
            System.out.println(kwhUsed);
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader("C:\\Users\\kyle\\Desktop\\CustomerCode.txt"));
                String s2;
                for (int g = 0; g<index+10; g++){
                    s2 = br.readLine();
                    if (g==index+10){
                        customer1 = s2;
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception one){
                return;
            }
                int customer = Integer.parseInt(customer1);
                 if (bool) {
                if (customer >0 && customer < 6)
                {
                    ccode.setText("Customer Code: " + customer + " - residential");
                    if (kwhUsed<=100)
                        payment = kwhUsed * 1.50;
                    else if (kwhUsed > 100 && kwhUsed<=200)
                        payment = kwhUsed * 2.0;
                    else if (kwhUsed > 200)
                        payment = kwhUsed * 3;
                }
                else if (customer >5 && customer <11)
                {
                    ccode.setText("Customer Code: " + customer + " - commercial");
                    if (kwhUsed<=100)
                        payment = kwhUsed * 3;
                    else if (kwhUsed > 100 && kwhUsed<=200)
                        payment = kwhUsed * 4;
                    else if (kwhUsed > 200)
                        payment = kwhUsed * 5;
                }

        }
        else
        {
            mReadAndNum.write(numText + "\n");
            mReadAndNum.write(readText + "");
            mReadAndNum.close();
        }
        mnum.setText("Meter Number: " + numText);
        prevmread.setText("Previous Meter reading: " +
                pMRead1 );
        presmread.setText("Present meter reading: " + readText);
        kwh.setText("Kilowatt Hour used: " + kwhUsed);
        amount.setText("Amount to be paid: P" + payment);
        Replacement();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\kyle\\Desktop\\MeterReadingAndNumber.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            list.add(s.nextLine());
        }
        s.close();
        updateList.setText("<html>Updated 2d arraylist:<br/><html>" +
                list);
    } catch (Exception r)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  What input(s) have caused it?

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Debugging software, especially small snippets of code like this, is a skill you'll have to pick up, and the answer isn't always going to be "ask the Internet". The error should give you a line number, so go to that line and see if there's any possible mistakes you could have made.

Comment: Are you sure your file has 10 lines?

Comment: @ScottHunter The error occurs when i input 10001 for the meter number and 5000 for the meter reading. How the program works is that when i input meter number in the file which is 10001 to 10010 it then continues on with the computation and the meter reading is just a part of the computation it should accept any integer input.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm sorry I was trying really hard to check and see for the error but i can't see it. I also can't see which line produces the error because the whole method is inside a try catch block so when the error happens all i know is that it catches it.

Comment: @Spectric the text file has 20 lines the first 10 being the meter numbers the next 10 being the previous meter readings.

Comment: Can you take it out of the try/catch block, for debugging purposes?

Comment: @ScottHunter I already tried this earlier but it says that I have to put the .write and the .close and other stuff that I think are called methods? in a try catch block. Also my replacement method also need to be put inside a try catch block. When I run the program it says "java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown".

Answer (score 0):

Change the second `for` loop to this:

```java
for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) {
    s1 = br.readLine();
    if (h == index + 10) {
        pMRead = s1;
    }
}
```

In your previous `for` loop you checked whether the current line was equal to `numText`, and if so, you would set `index` to `index` + `g`. However, if `g` is bigger than 0 and the current line was equal to `numText`, you would find yourself with this:

```
for (int h = 0; h < 2 + 10; h++) {
    s1 = br.readLine();
    if (h == index + 10) {
        pMRead = s1;
    }
}
```

And since you said your file is 20 lines (10 of which had already been read in the first loop), this would exceed the total lines, and thus throw an error.

Comment: I will try this Thank you very much!

Comment: It still doesn't work I don't know why. It still gives me the exception in my try catch block.

Comment: @lightbrid Can you print the stack trace? Use `one.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` block

Comment: This is what it says in the compiler 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:670)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
at com.kyle.Main.actionPerformed(Main.java:137) <4 internal lines>
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279) <30 internal lines>